# How can I get a 1 to -1 float value from the localEulerAngels of a third person camera in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, trigonometry

I have a have a ball with a rigidbody attached and I am adding torque to the ball based on the angle of a third person camera (always looking at the ball)  witch rotates around the ball.  I am trying to change the direction of the ball based on the position of the camera in its rotation around the ball.  I am using `Vector3.right` for forward and reverse torque and `Vector3.back` for right and left.  I have the forward/reverse value, `rightVal`  working but I have been working on the left/right value, `backVal` for three days and am at a loss.  Here is how I am trying to accomplish this.

```
 void CalcRightVal()
        {
             float degrees = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y;
            if (degrees > 0 && degrees < 180.0f)
            {
                rightVal = (-degrees / 360) * 4 + 1;
            }


            if (degrees > 180.0f && degrees < 360.0f) //
            {
                rightVal = (-degrees / 360) * 4 + 1;

                if (rightVal < -1.0f)
                {
                    rightVal = (degrees / 360) * 4 - 3;
                }
            }

        }

        void ApplyTorque()
        {
            Vector3 dir = new Vector3(rightVal, 0, backVal);
            ball.AddTorque(dir * ballAcceleration);
        }
```

In `ApplyTorque()` I need the `backVal` to go from 0 to -1 i.e. `Vector3.back` when `degrees == 90`.  Then `backVal` should increase in value to 0 when `degrees == 180` then up to 1 when `degrees == 270` then back to 0 when `degrees == 360`.  This will apply torque to the right when the camera is at 90 degrees and left when the camera is at 270 degrees.  The Idea is that the user will add input to forward i.e. `KeyCode.W` to add acceleration and reverse or `KeyCode.S` for breaks.  The camera will be responsible for changing the direction of the force.  I am not terrible at math but this one has me beat.

While `rightVal` is at 1 or -1, `backVal` needs to be at 0 and vice versa.  That way when the camera is directly behind the ball or 0 degrees the torque applied will be `Vector3.right` or `(1, 0, 0)` and when the camera is at 90 degrees or on the left of the ball, torque applied will be `Vector3.back` or `(0, 0, -1)`.  This will apply torque to make the ball turn right.  Basically wherever the camera is the ball rolls forward from the point of view of the user.  Thank you for the help, and all help is always appreciated.

Here is a graphic to help out.

[image]
Thank You.

Comment: Can you just use a sine like this: `backVal = Mathf.Sin((degrees - 180) * Mathf.Deg2Rad)`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a smoothed increase/decrease of the backval you can simply do:

```
    backVal = -Mathf.Sin(degrees * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
```

If you want a linear relation however, it will be slightly more complicated:

```
private void CalcBackValue()
{
    float degrees = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.z;
    if (degrees >= 0 && degrees < 90)
        backVal = -degrees / 90f; // 0 to -1
    else if (degrees >= 90 && degrees < 270)
        backVal = -2 + degrees / 90; // -1 to 0 to 1
    else if (degrees >= 270 && degrees < 360)
        backVal = 4 - degrees / 90; // 1 to 0
}
```

You will probably need to expand on this to include the negative euler angles, but essentially you are finding the values along the following curves in the second example:

[image]